# Build multidimensional array for json output

Tags: php, json

Looking to output json in the following format:

```
 [{"Montgomery":[{"red":"12:34:56","yellow":"11:44:46","orange":"10:54:36","green":"9:24:26","purple":"8:14:16"}],"Suburban":[{"red":"12:34:56","yellow":"11:44:46","orange":"10:54:36","green":"9:24:26","purple":"8:14:16"}],"Shady Grove Adventist":[{"red":"12:34:56","yellow":"11:44:46","orange":"10:54:36","green":"9:24:26","purple":"8:14:16"}],"Holy Cross":[{"red":"12:34:56","yellow":"11:44:46","orange":"10:54:36","green":"9:24:26","purple":"8:14:16"}],"Washington Adventist":[{"red":"12:34:56","yellow":"11:44:46","orange":"10:54:36","green":"9:24:26","purple":"8:14:16"}]}]
```

My code:

```
 $xyz[] = array("Montgomery"=> array("Red" => "12:00", "Yellow" => "14:00"));
 $xyz[] = array("Suburban"=> array("Yellow" => "16:00"));

 echo '[' . json_encode($xyz) . ']';
```

My results:

```
[[{"Montgomery":{"Red":"12:00","Yellow":"14:00"}},{"Suburban":{"Yellow":"16:00"}}]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the structure:

```
$container = array();
$container['Montgomery'] = array(array('red' => '12:34:56', 'yellow' => '11:44:46'));
$container['Suburban'] = array(array('red' => '12:34:56', 'yellow' => '11:44:46'));
echo json_encode(array($container));
```

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for... @wwwslinger: I wanted to keep it all in an array and not create a class, but excellent options, thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

You could use objects, something like this (you'll want to clean it up a bit):

```
class Church {
  public $red = "";
  public $yellow = "";
  public $orange = "";
  public $green = "";
  public $purple = "";
}
class XYZ {
  public $Montgomery = new Church();
  public $Shad_Grove_Adventist = new Church();
  public $Holy_Cross = new Church();
  public $Washington_Adventist = new Church();
}

$xyz = new XYZ();
$xyz->Montgomery->red = "12:00";
...
```

then output your JSON:

```
echo '[' . json_encode($xyz) . ']';
```

It won't be a perfect match to your desired JSON output, but it will give better readability and much more flexibility.

Comment: how is this a valid variable with a space? `public $Shad_Grove Adventist` ? ;)

Comment: Sorry, it needs underscores.

Answer (score 0):

You're desired output has an array `[]` as its top level item. `[]` in JSON corresponds to a numeric array in PHP. A JSON array is used to contain an ordered collection of items.

Your top-level array contains one item, a JSON object `{}`. A PHP object (stdClass) or associative array will convert to this in JSON. A JSON object is used to create collections of key-value pairs.

To produce your desired output, build your data in PHP like this:

```
// Top-level numeric array.
$container = array();

// Only item in top-level array.
$item = array();

// The value of each of these items will be a numeric array.
$item['Montgomery'] = array();

// Create a new associative array, and push that onto the list array.
$subItem = array("red" => "12:34:56",
        "yellow" => "11:44:46",
        "orange" => "10:54:36",
        "green" => "9:24:26",
        "purple" => "8:14:16");
$item['Montgomery'][] = $subItem;
$container[] = $item; 

// ...Add more items...

print json_encode($container);
```

Or, if you want to build it all at once:

```
$container = array(
    array(
        "Montgomery" => array(
            array("red" => "12:34:56",
                "yellow" => "11:44:46",
                "orange" => "10:54:36",
                "green" => "9:24:26",
                "purple" => "8:14:16"
            )
        )
        // ...More items...
    )
);

print json_encode($container);
```

Notice that there are places that have an array inside an array. This is to build an associative array and add it as the only member of a numeric array. This corresponds to having a `{}` inside `[]`.